# Encoding two floats in a double without loosing precision

Tags: java, graphics, coordinates, primitive-types

How can I store two `float` values in a `double` without loosing precision in Java?

I need to do so to reduce (X,Y) coordinates into one location value.

Comment: Just concatenate the bits (e.g. with a `union` in C++)? I am unsure what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I was using Java. So I can concat the bits then without the JVM doing anything fuzzy right?

Comment: Why would the JVM do anything fuzzy? The result will obviously not be a meaningful double. Please add appropriate language tags. I have added the Java tag for you on this question.